# How to detect another MKAnnotaion pin when touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I have multiple annotation pin in `map(place1,place2)`

I want user touch pin to go to new `Viewcontroller` to get description of place

it have function to detect in pin to touch it to go to `descriptionViewController`?

This is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


MKCoordinateRegion place1 = { {0.0, 0.0} , {0.0, 0.0} };
place1.center.latitude = 34.7037755;
place1.center.longitude = 137.7345882;
place1.span.longitudeDelta = 0.02f;
place1.span.latitudeDelta = 0.02f;
[mapView setRegion:place1 animated:YES];

Newclass *ann1 = [[Newclass alloc] init];
ann1.title = @"Place1";
ann1.subtitle = @"subtitle";
ann1.coordinate = place1.center;
[mapView addAnnotation: ann1];

MKCoordinateRegion place2 = { {0.0, 0.0} , {0.0, 0.0} };
place2.center.latitude = 34.7024461;
place2.center.longitude = 137.7297572;
place2.span.longitudeDelta = 0.02f;
place2.span.latitudeDelta = 0.02f;
[mapView setRegion:place2 animated:YES];

Newclass *ann2 = [[Newclass alloc] init];
ann2.title = @"place2";
ann2.subtitle = @"subtitle";
ann2.coordinate = place2.center;
[mapView addAnnotation:ann2];


}

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{
MKPinAnnotationView *myPin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"current"];
myPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;

UIButton *advertButtom = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[advertButtom addTarget:self action:@selector(button:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

myPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = advertButtom;
myPin.draggable =NO;
myPin.animatesDrop =true;
myPin.canShowCallout=YES;

return myPin;

}

-(void)button:(id)sender{
NSUserDefaults *defults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [self storyboard];
descriptionViewController *description = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"des"];
[self presentModalViewController:description animated:YES];


NSLog(@"touched");
NSLog(@"data %@");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use mapView method

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
         NSUserDefaults *defults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
         UIStoryboard *storyboard = [self storyboard];
         descriptionViewController *description = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"des"];
         [self presentModalViewController:description animated:YES];


         NSLog(@"touched");
         NSLog(@"data %@");
    }
```

Comment: how to change action in `action:@selector(button:)`

Comment: Remove button and when user click on annotation didSelectAnnotation method will perform

Comment: Yes it Works but How I can check if ann1 or ann2 touched

Comment: You have (view:MKAnnotationView) in method and that view contain view that you make in viewForAnnotation. You can put some id in that view and chack later when get it in didSelect method